# On subsonic3 How to get the name of a field from a table, and the max length, type etc

Tags: field, subsonic3, maxlength

How to get the string-name of a field from a table on subsonic 3?

On subsonic version 2 I use the TableName.columns.Field

Also in subsonic 2 I have the opportunity to get the max length of a string field.
How can I do that on subsonic 3 ?

Comment: @downvoter after two years and on a dead project - why the -1 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up that we need to change the tt files and create that fields.

Of cource maybe they was better to exist in the default files, however they not

here is the page for how to create the dal for t4
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Creating_Your_Own_DAL

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the code in front of me but you can access some of the table info such as the column names by using [TableName]Table.columns , replace [TableName] with the name of your table